# Error: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain

Tags: java, spring, struts2, spring-security, security

I am migrating a Java Struts 2 Web App from Spring 2.5.x to Spring 3.1.x. I am using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE with all the necessary modules. I have this App Context file being loaded for Spring Security configuration:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http realm="Company" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/drivermaintenance.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_NUMBER_INQUIRY,ACTION_MAINTAIN_DRIVER_NUMBER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/exceptioncheckin.action" access="ACTION_EXCEPTIONS_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/routesnotcheckedin.action" access="ACTION_ROUTES_NOT_CHECKED_IN_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkininquiryfilters.action" access="ACTION_CHECK_IN_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkininquirydata.action" access="ACTION_CHECK_IN_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/acceptduplicateroute.action" access="ACTION_ACCEPT_DUPLICATE_ROUTE" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/drivercreditinquirydata.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CREDITS_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/drivercreditinquirynavigationbaseddata.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CREDITS_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/cashtochargeinquirydata.action" access="ACTION_CASH_TO_CHARGE_INVOICES_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/cashtochargeinquiryfilter.action" access="ACTION_CASH_TO_CHARGE_INVOICES_INQUIRY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/exitdrivercheckin.action" access="ACTION_EXIT_CHECKIN_LOGOUT,ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/routecheckin.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/startnewroutecheckin.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findroute.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saveroutecheckin.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findcustomerdelivery.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/savecustomerdelivery.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findoverage.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/updateoverage.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removeoverage.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/navigatefromoverage.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findcreditpickup.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/savecreditpickup.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/finddrivercredit.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/addlineitem.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/updatecredit.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removecredit.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removelineitem.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/creditissuedetails.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findproductdescription.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/creditwholeinvoice.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/canceldrivercredit.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/navigatefromdrivercredit.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findsummarytable.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findtripday.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findtripdescriptiondetails.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/savetripday.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/drivercheckin.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/savedrivercheckin.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/finddrivercheckin.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removeroutefromcheckin.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removetripfromcheckin.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removeadditionalservicefromcheckin.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removebackhaulfromcheckin.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findadditionalservice.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saveadditionalservice.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findbalancetime.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/savebalancetime.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findbackhaul.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findbackhauldetail.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removebackhaul.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/findbackhaulpolist.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/savebackhaul.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/drivercheckinindex.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/newdrivercheckin.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/finddrivercollection.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/savedrivercollection.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_CHECK_IN,ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/modifypayments.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/modifyprimarypayment.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/shiftamount.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/modifydepositamount.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/retrievecredit.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/addpreviouspayment.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/removepreviouspayment.action" access="ACTION_SAVE_DRIVER_CHECK_IN" />

        <security:http-basic />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logout.jsp" />

        <!-- Pages/items that don't require passwords.  It is particularly important that
         the ping page appear here, or the DCI monitoring will break. -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/ping.jsp"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied.jsp"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**"/>
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

But I keep getting this error, which says I have a universal pattern defined before other patterns and so the other patterns won't be match... but I don't:

```
ERROR 2012-11-09 17:10:58,167 [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[serverurl.here.com].[/appDir]]: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkPathOrder(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.validate(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.afterPropertiesSet(FilterChainProxy.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 36 more
```

I am lost and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there maybe another context that also defines a `<security:http>` namespace?

Comment: No other context uses Spring Security namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after lots of different sets of eyes looking at the project, it looks as though it was likely a dependency conflict problem. The most likely candidate was where we were still importing spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.7 while we are using the 3.1.2 Spring version. We removed this dependency as cleaning up a lot of other dependency conflicts and the application starts up as it should.

Thank you for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

regards to the documentation [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal), you should try this:

```
  <http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>

  <http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
  </http>
```

my suggestion is, you should put the following block on the top of the stack.

```
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ping.jsp"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied.jsp"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**"/>

    // here comes all other configurations
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/drivermaintenance.action" access="ACTION_DRIVER_NUMBER_INQUIRY,ACTION_MAINTAIN_DRIVER_NUMBER" />
    ....
```

Comment: I tried the first code snippet by having the block of 4 no security matchers outside the main http block, each as their own http element. That didn't help. I'll try just moving them to the top of the block like in your second code snippet.

Comment: If you cannot fix it at weekend, i can show you my configuration on monday

Answer (score 1):

Please see: [A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2034)

Comment: I am deploying this to Tomcat 6. In that issue he says it works fine in Tomcat 7, but not in Websphere 7. I am not using Spring Roo and that issue was closed as "Invalid".

Comment: If the issue is with the configuration being picked twice or another configuration being picked as well, try removing either and both the lines with `**` and see if you can narrow down the problem